# Access remote windows machine file using c#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2017, remote-access

I want to access a log file located on a remote machine using c#. I have the following code.

```
NetworkCredential theNetworkCredential = new NetworkCredential(@"manaf", "manaf123");
CredentialCache theNetCache = new CredentialCache();
theNetCache.Add(new Uri(@"\\mypc"), "Basic", theNetworkCredential);
string[] theFolders = Directory.GetDirectories(@"\\myDirectory");
```

I had already given read permission on the remote folder and file.

```
file://mypc/myDirectory
```

But I got an error like this

```
System.IO.IOException: 'The specified path is invalid : '\\myDirectory''
```

Comment: wouldnt @"\\mydirectory" be seen as \\mydirectory and therefore treated like \\machine01.. surely you would be looking for c:\ ? or enumerate drives..

Comment: Did you make the folder shared so it can be seen across the network?  Make sure you can see the file in a window explorer before trying your software again.

Comment: You still need a path like `\\mypc\myDirectory`. The name of the shared folder alone is not enough as path.